# Extract a specific value from some printed data in stdout by C++

Tags: c++, regex

I use a simulator (ndnSIM) in Linux which is based on the C++. After doing some tasks, it prints an output in each second in the `stdout` by this command:

`L3RateTracer::InstallAll ("-", Seconds (1));`. This is constant and I cannot change its format to print the output in a string or an array. I want to extract a specific data from this output from `stdout`. For instance, the output in the 1st second has been printed in `stdout` as follows (the space between each feature is by Tab):

```
1   C1  0   1   Out1    268 335 0
1   C1  0   2   Out2    0   0   0
1   C2  1   1   Out1    0   0   0
1   R3  1   1   Out2    317 0   0
1   P1  -1  all Sat1    268 0   335
1   C1  -1  all Tim1    0   0   0
1   R2  1   9   Out1    0   0   0
```

I need to extract 6th column data for those outputs which are "R3" in 2nd column and "Out2" in 5th column. In this example, the desired value is "317".

How can I extract this value (=317) in each second from the printed output in the `stdout` by C++?

Comment: Do you have to do it in `C++`? Why not pipe it through `awk` first?

Comment: Yes, i need to perform in `C++`. i am not familiar with `awk`.

Comment: `awk '{print $6}` is all you need for this.

Comment: If you need to do it in C++, use `strtok()` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: How can i connected the `stdout` results in `awk`? Could you please tell me the correct format of coding?

Comment: @Barmar, `strtok` sucks, we need a `std::split()` in the standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a regex for this, or anything, if you don't have to.

What you need to do is read in the file, split it by tabs and/or spaces, I can't tell, and then retrieve the element you want.

Read about how to split strings here:
[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

to read from `stdin`, which is what it looks like you want to do, you need to do this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

When combined with the string splitting method above, it will work wonderfully.
You will then be able to `ToolThatPrintsThings | YourNewTool`

Comment: It seems fine. What does it mean by ToolThatPrintsThings | YourNewTool

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, line)` waits for inputting my data in command line. But i need to capture data itself from auto-generated data in the `stdout`, not wait for inputting data by human.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
ndnSIM | awk '{print $6}' | yourProg
```

Now `yourProg` just has to read each line with `cin::getline()`, which will be column 6 from the ndnSIM output.

Comment: I should use your suggested solution in the command line? such as this one: `./waf --run=MyProg | awk '{print $6}' | cin::getline()`? But i think i misunderstood! First pipe is the command of running ndnSIM simulator.

Comment: `cin::getline()` is something you write in your C++ program to read a line from standard input. It's not a shell command.

Comment: What is the library of 'awk' to declare it?

Comment: It's not a library, it's a shell command.

Comment: Don't you recognize a Unix shell pipeline?

Comment: I think, it can also work in the program! I am not expert in C++. But, I need to extract column 6 or a specific data in column 6 and save it in a string in the program for further usage. How is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to make things harder for yourself. Use existing tools to simplify things. awk will extract column 6, then your C++ program only has to read a line from standard input.